# Different Bundle Identifier for Cocoapods frameworks not recognised

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoa, cocoapods

I am trying to upload an app in the AppStore. The app is divided into two, the app and the cocoapods frameworks. I have created a bundle identifier for the app with a corresponding provisioning profile. The frameworks come with their own bundle identifier and when I tried to replace them with my app bundle identifier the app returned the following error - "An error was encountered while running (Domain = LaunchServicesError, Code = 0)". Therefore I am assuming that the bundle identifier of the cocoapods framework needs to remain as is. Therefore I created a provisioning profile for each of the three bundle identifiers assuming this would resolve the issue.

With this, both the build and archive are successful however when I am uploading the archived app into the app store, xcode is returning the following error - "iTunes Store operation failed. No suitable application records were found. Verify your bundle identifier".

I have tried to reset the bundle id and provision profile from the preference in xcode however issue persist. The build settings - code signing correspond to the respective provisioning profile.

My questions are;

1) Can I have more than one provisioning profile for an app ? (ie. am I doing it right in creating provisioning profile for the cocoapods frameworks).

2) If so, why the provisioning profile is not being recognised (ie. marked as none) once it is archived ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I'm interested by an answer, did you fixed it ?